# Include or not my messages in HttpResponseRedirect?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

So far (1) and (2) are producing the same results in my Development Django environment. But are they really equivalent, or I will end up loosing some messages in a setting I can not predict in advance?

```
(1)

return HttpResponseRedirect('/my/home/page', messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'My message here'))

(2)

messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'My message here')
return HttpResponseRedirect('/my/home/page')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ways work because `messages.add_message()` adds the message to your `request.session` in-place. But the first looks very strange. The `add_message` doesn't return anything helpful to include in the `HttpResponseRedirect`. So I believe you should go with the second option:

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'My message here')
return HttpResponseRedirect('/my/home/page')
```

or, using a couple of shortcuts,

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

messages.info(request, 'My message here')
return redirect('/my/home/page')
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. I was puzzled because both are producing the same result.